# Android: Observing SMS for Deleted Threads

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I've currently written an app that is observing the content://sms URI for any changes to the database. My observer is successfully being triggered when individual messages are added or removed, however, no notification is triggered when an entire thread is deleted at once. Is there any way to get this event to trigger? Or maybe there's another content provider I should be observing?

```
Uri URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
String[] columns = {"_id", "date"};
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(URI, columns, "type=?", new String[]{"1"}, "_id DESC");

Observer observer = new Observer();
c.registerContentObserver(observer);
```

And my observer class:

```
private class Observer extends ContentObserver {

    public Observer() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        if (!selfChange) {
            // do stuff
            // never called when a thread is deleted
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Update:
I've been trying to come up with ways to work around this issue, such as redetermining the IDs I need when new messages come in, but nothing has proven successful. My observer needs to be signaled when a thread is deleted. Does anybody know what the problem is? Or is there another way I can listen for deleted threads?

Comment: Can my application know which sms is deleted ?? i means its content. Because i need to store that deleted message? Thank you....

Comment: Not that I know of. Observing the database will only alert you after the message has been deleted, so you won't be able to query for its information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I switched to observing the content://mms-sms/conversations content provider. This provider properly signals my observer when a thread is deleted.